# Ubuntu server reports incorrect RAM

Tags: server, ram

Just yesterday I installed new RAM modules to my home server with Ubuntu server 20.04.1
I was changing drives as well so I installed fresh copy of Ubuntu server but unfortunatelly Ubuntu now reports that I have 16 Gigs of usable RAM instead of 32 but it seems that it recognizes the RAM just fine.

lshw -C memory:

```
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: P5.40
       date: 07/03/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 10
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3000C16-8GISB
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 768KiB
       capacity: 768KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 14
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

free -m

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16004        1237       13455           1        1311       14507
Swap:          4095           0        4095
```

dmidcode --type memory

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.1 present.
# SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.2.0 are not
# fully supported by this version of dmidecode.

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 128 GB
        Error Information Handle: 0x000F
        Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: 0x0016
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: F4-3000C16-8GISB
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: 0x0019
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: F4-3000C16-8GISB
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: 0x001C
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 0
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: F4-3000C16-8GISB
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0010
        Error Information Handle: 0x001F
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 1
        Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Unknown
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: F4-3000C16-8GISB
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 1866 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
        Memory Technology: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Memory Operating Mode Capability: None
        Firmware Version: Unknown
        Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Module Product ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
        Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
        Non-Volatile Size: None
        Volatile Size: None
        Cache Size: None
        Logical Size: None
```

Comment: Which CPU and motherboard are you using? Some i5 CPUs are capped at 16GB regardless of how much physical memory is installed.

Comment: I have Ryzen 5 2700X with ASRock X370 Killer SLI.

Comment: The [2700X is a Ryzen 7 based on ASRock's CPU Support list](https://www.asrock.com/support/cpu.asp?s=AM4), and it uses a Pinnacle Ridge core. Based on [the specs for your motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/X370%20Taichi/index.asp#Specification), 1866MT/s RAM isn't supported with that particular processor. I wonder if this has something to do with it. 

Comment: Well I had 32 gigs of RAM when i used that MB CPU combo for Windows and had no problems with it.

Well now i tried to change the RAM with my personal PC and When I have 3 x 8GBs it only shows 8 GB in Ubuntu and I tried all the combinations. When I have 2x 8GBs it show 16 like it should.

Comment: Okay, actually after messing around randomly the other 16 gigs just poped up.